# Converting from Object[][] to ImageIcon

Tags: java, swing, converters, imageicon

I am trying to convert my `object[][]` to an `ImageIcon`. I current have a `public Object[][] images;` where I store my images. How do I convert this to an ImageIcon so that I can use it to put it into my JTable? I have tried this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
...
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(images[i].toString());
    // add to table
}
```

Nothing shows in my table and if I print the value out from the cell this shows: `[Ljava.lang.String;@72787a6f`

Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a 2D array so you need to use another index to reference the element at row `i` column `j`

```
for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) { 
       for (int j = 0; j < images[i].length; j++) { 
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(images[i][j].toString());
            ...
       }
}
```

It would make more sense to use a `String[][]` array

Comment: Okay, if I changed my list to a 1D array do you think that would make it easier?

Comment: I have no need for a 2D array when I think about it, so I guess it would be easier with 1D array